# How do I retrieve files or audio files programmatically from the device?

Tags: android

I want to know how to get the ringtone,audio files in the device and I want set them as alarm. How to do it?

I am working in the code to set the alarm and I want to know how to retreive audio or ringtones from the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs on RingtoneManager and Ringtone

> [RingtoneManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html)
>
> [Ringtone](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/media/Ringtone.html)

Comment: Hi donal i found ringtonemanager to be useful,and i found getCursor() method .i think it will provides audio files in the device.If it is true i want to know sample program how to invoke them

Comment: Sorry I dont have any code at hand, google ringtone picker source code and see if it brings up anything